# What does "french me" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was watching Dexter series when Vince Masuka said to Debra: "You will have to french me."

So what does it mean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means "You will have to give me a French kiss" which means kissing with tongues.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that phrase is commonly used now and it means giving french kiss. Latest reference I saw to this was in [modern family](http://youtu.be/9-P80zKvL1A).

[image]